# organization chart with click

Tags: php, html

I am new and I want to ask, if I click a specific block in the organization chart it goes to a specific `href` link. the thing is the organization chart I am using is in 1 picture

[image]

what I want is when I click the first block in left first row it goes to `link A` and when I click the second block in left second row it goes to `link B`

or is there any other way to approach it ? maybe some link
P.S: now, the organization chart is in one picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`<map>` and `<area>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) elements, and set the coordinates to the areas of the image that you want to have a particular href:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets"
usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Comment: thanks for the reference, but is there an easy way to know how big and where is coordinate shape